# Swift 5. Display array from the 2nd tableview cell ( 2nd indexpath.row )

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, cell

I have a tableview with 2 prototype cells that are 3 rows. The 1st prototype cell just has a view. The 2nd prototype cell has a button.
The 1st prototype cell is just 1 row which is also the first indexpath.row
The 2nd prototype cell has 2 rows. ( 2nd and 3rd indexpath.row )

I want to merge my model ( array ) with the 2nd and 3rd rows. But the app crashes and said out of range.

Tableview class

```
let modelArray = [phone, remote]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return 1 + modelArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
UITableViewCell {
if indexPath.row < 1 {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CELL1", for: 
indexPath) as! CELL1
cell.view.backgroundColor = .red
return cell
}
let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CELL2", for: indexPath)  
CELL2
```

This is where I am getting the out of range error. ( I tried it without the + 1 as well )

```
cell2.configure(title: modelArray[indexpath.row + 1])
return cell2
}
```

CELL2 class

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonName: UIButton!
private var title: String = ""

func configure(title: String) {
self.title = title
buttonName.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your modelArray have only 2 element and you are trying to get 3rd element value.

let's suppose when `indexPath` is 0 then `tableview` renders the CELL1 and when `indexPath` is incremented, we can say it when `indexPath` is 1 then your getting the value from your modelArray like below :

```
cell2.configure(title: modelArray[indexpath.row + 1])
```

which is getting the value modelArray[1+1] that turns in modelArray[2] but modelArray doesn't contains modelArray[2], it has only 0 and 1 element.

try with by subtracting 1 from current `indexPath`.

```
cell2.configure(title: modelArray[indexpath.row - 1])
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the breakdown

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the logic:  `cellForRow` is called three times (1 + 2), but there is no item at index 3 in the array (nor at index 2 without `+1`).

According to the code the cell at `indexPath.row == 1` is supposed to display the first item in the array (index 0) and the cell at `indexPath.row == 2` the second item (index 1).

So you have to **subtract** 1

```
cell2.configure(title: modelArray[indexpath.row - 1])
```

Comment: It worked,,, thanks